# how to copy modules from one virtualenv to another

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, pip

Is it possibe to copy python modules from one virtualenv to another.If so how is this done?

Answer (score 53):

As long as you're moving them from one virtualenv to another on the *same* machine, you could easily just do:

```
$ cp -r [env1]/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages/* [env2]/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages/
```

However, if the environments are on different machines or utilizing different versions of python or some other major difference, it's probably not a good idea. In general it's much safer to generate a `requirements.txt`, and then use that to load up all the same modules in the other environment. You can create the file manually if you like, but it's easier to just use `pip`.

```
$ pip freeze -E [env1] > requirements.txt
```

Or, if your virtualenv is activated already, you can simply do:

```
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Then, in your other environment, you can do:

```
$ pip install -E [env2] -r /path/to/requirements.txt
```

Comment: will anything go wrong if i just attempt to copy *one* package like this?

Comment: The problem is not in the *quantity* of packages copied, but any differences in Python versions, system architectures, etc., between the source and destination. If source and destination are on the same machine, you should be fine; if they are on different machines, you should use `pip freeze`.

Answer (score 3):

I am working on a 64bit machine with Ubuntu-14.04-64. I compiled and installed python-3.4.3 to */opt/python3.4/* and created a vitualenv based on this python.

```
mkvirtualenv -p /opt/python3.4/bin/python venv1
```

Also for ease:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualenvwrapper
```

With the venv installed and working with PyQt5 successfully (the hard bit) plus numpy, scipy, ipython etc.
I installed virtualenv-clone:

```
workon myvenv
pip install virtual-clone
deactivate
```

and then ran:

```
virtualenv-clone venv1 venv2
```

PyQt5 works this way. The command-line prompt still names *venv1* as active but within *~/.virtualenv/venv2*

```
cat activate* | grep "venv1"
```

shows 3 entries within the three files *activate*, *activate.csh*, and *activate.fish*

In activate, change

```
if [ "x(myvenv1) " != x ] ; then
        PS1="(myvenv1) $PS1"
else
```

to

```
...
        PS1="(myvenv2) $PS1"
...
```

In *activate.csh* change

```
if ("venv1" != "") then
        set env_name = "venv1"
else
```

to

```
...
    set env_name = "venv2"
...
```

In *activate.fish* change

```
if test -n "(venv1) "
        printf "%s%s%s" "(venv1) " (set_color normal) (_old_fish_prompt)
        return
end
```

to

```
...
    printf "%s%s%s" "(venv2) " (set_color normal) (_old_fish_prompt)
...
```

Now when you `source ~/.virtualenv/venv2/bin/activate` or `workon venv2` the command prompt will correctly display your environment (the cloned copy of venv1).

Edit: this doesn't answer the question *"How to copy modules from one virtualenv to another"* but I'm pretty sure the result is in many cases the desired one, namely the creation of a new venv based on a previously created one which includes (all of) the previously installed modules.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you are able to copy the .egg-info from the lib/site-packages folder of the virtualenv to the lib/site-packages of the other environment.

Answer (score 1):

seems like we can't just copy one virtualenv as another one.
even you chnage the $VIRTUAL_ENV in the activate file, it still act as in origin virtualenv and pip will install all the packages to origin site-packages/

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a problem installing 'wordcloud' on another Python venv on Windows 10. Package was installed on another project, same machine.

copy "wordcloud" and "wordcloud-1.8.1.dist-info" folders from `Users/<user>/PycharmProjects/<projectname>/venv/Lib/site-packages` and paste to your new project `/<projectname>/venv/Lib/site-packages`.