# Managing third party modules after upgrading Python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, pip

Do we need to re-install all the third party modules if we upgrade to a higher version of Python or is there an easier way out?

Comment: Is re-install difficult?

Comment: Which 3rd party modules? Upgrading from what version to what version? You need to check with those libraries. They usually tell users what range of Python vesions they support. Many still don't support Python 3.

Comment: Difficult or no, it is surely time-consuming if there are many modules

Comment: @CppLearner, Say if a module supports both python2.6 and python2.7, can i simply copy-paste it from site-packages (sorry if i sound dumb on this)?

Comment: No you should not copy and paste even if doing so work. I haven't tried that but I think there will be some headaches. Are you using the site-wide global Python? If so, start using virtulanev and Pip. And are you using working on a project or what?

Comment: Anyway, regardless of whether you use the global python or virtualenv, you should install pip, and then do  ``pip freeze > packages.txt`` and then supply ``pip install -r packages.txt`` and let pip helps you install all the packages. Some of them might fail.

Comment: @CppLearner actually I changed laptops recently, due to which i had to reinstall python. I have chosen the latest stable version 2.7.4, previously I was using version 2.7.x (I dont exactly remember which one). I write some utility scripts on python, and usually work with numpy/scipy.

Comment: @hardikudeshi so you want to migrate all the tools you have from old laptop to the new laptop? or do you still have the same OS? I guess the former?

Comment: @CppLearner Yes even that should work for me, its not terribly important for me to have the latest python version

Comment: @hardikudeshi let's clarify this, sorry, you got a new laptop. are you running a fresh system or did you just move the hard drive to the new laptop? it seems like you have a new laptop, new OS, new python version by default, and now you want all the old libraries that you were using in the old laptop to exist in the new laptop. you want to copy-paste because you some of the tools like numpy scipy requires C libraries and can take a while. confirm me please.

Comment: You should indicate your OS and if you are using pip, virtualenv or not.

Comment: @CppLearner I have a new Laptop, OS remains the same (win 7). The old libraries I was using continue to exist in the new laptop. But I installed the latest python version (v2.7.4) on the new laptop. Now i am trying to see if the old libraries can be copy-pasted to the new python version (i think it is not a good idea, based on discussion above). Also, it is not important for me to upgrade to latest python version. I can continue to use the old python version, if it makes life any easier.

Comment: @LTWorf I am using Windows 7, I have pip, but am not very comfortable using it. Though I have used it before, with help from SO. I do not use virtualenv

Comment: Oh windows. Sometimes I feel like windows is the end of the world. no just kidding :) from http://stackoverflow.com/a/8794404/230884 it seems like in theory you could. You can try, doesn't hurt at all. Is there any reason to use 2.7.4 for your scientific purpose? I heard 2.7.4 fixed some serious memory leak for some rare cases.

Comment: Thanks i will check that out. I am simply using it since it is recommended as the latest stable version for python. Thanks again

Comment: @CppLearner I guess even there they are not much recommending copy-paste. I better re-install them. Thanks.

Comment: @hardikudeshi no problem. check out my comment on pip freeze and install. but hey, do whatever works for you!

Answer (score 1):

Many module developers provide different versions of their modules for Python 2.x and Python 3.x.

But yes, you will need to individually re-install different versions of the modules you're using if you're calling them from a totally different version of Python. How easy it will be depends on which modules you're using.

That being said, if you're upgrading to a new sub-version (such as 2.6 -> 2.7 or 3.2 -> 3.3) you won't need to worry about reinstalling the modules.

Answer (score 1):

For example, if you are using Python 2.6 and you want to move to 2.7 you can easily install [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) for Python 2.7 or [easy_install](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall) for 2.7 and install the package you want, I could say nearly all of the modules of 2.6 DO support 2.7, since the changes hasn't been much as python 3x.

If you are upgrading from Python 2 to python 3, there are a few modules that do not support Python 3, sometimes there are a few hacks. for small libs, [2to3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) works fine.

Also check [3to2](http://wiki.python.org/moin/3to2).