# How to install module from another python installation

Tags: python

I am using winpython. Now for simple distribution, I want to use winpython zero.
Is it possible to install the package from winpython folder to winpython zero folder?

Comment: Or, nobody uses winpython?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, a possible way would be to:

- download packages from https://sourceforge.net/projects/winpython/files/WinPython_Source/Do_It_Yourself/Winpython_2016-03/
- unzip them all in d:\toto
- then do

pip install the_package_i_want --no-index --find-links=d:\toto --trusted-host=None

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest ways is just copying the `site-package` directory in the original winpython to the new one (It is assumed that the versions of two winpythons are the same, saying python 3.5).

If you thinks the above way is silly, then you can use `pip` instead.

1. Extract the installed packages from original winpython
   (pip used below should belong to the **original** winpython)

   pip freeze --all > python_packages.txt
2. Install the extracted package list with pip.
   (pip used below should belong to the **new** winpython)

   pip install -r python_packages.txt

Comment: I don't want to download the package so pip will not help. Thanks for the answer. I have winpython which contains all installed package. Is it possible to extract that package and install it to the another python installtion?

Comment: @Scripting.FileSystemObject If you don't consider downloading, you can refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8794404/4136588). I think the 'brute-force copy' is the solution.