# copying modules from python 3.10 to 3.11

Tags: python, module, pip

So basically I installed 3.11(which is the latest release). But when I executed the exe file it said "install now" instead of "update now"(which I saw while updating from 3.10.5 to 3.10.8. Now installing would create a whole new directory and all of my important modules are in the dir "python3.10" and I'm too lazy to "pip install" every module to the new directory. So is there any way I could possibly update to 3.11 without creating a whole new directory and without separately installing all of my modules?

Comment: Modules could include native code and that is always compiled against specific Python version, hence modules are installed in directories that include the version in their name. You cannot simply move the modules and expect them to work, though Python-only modules will probably work. Freezing older version's modules and bulk-installing them through the requirements mechanism with the new version, as shown in DeepSpace's answer, is the way to go.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/8793877/4788546?

Answer (score 4):

***Assuming both interpreters are globally available, for example as `python3.10` and `python3.11`***

Get a list of all the modules installed on the 3.10 interpreter with [`pip freeze`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_freeze/) and then install them with 3.11's `pip`:

```bash
python3.10 -m pip freeze > requirements.txt
python3.11 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Of course, the success of this depends on each module's availability/support for Python 3.11.

**Manually copying the *site-packages* directory to a different interpreter is not suggested and is just asking for problems later down the road**.

Comment: i did this and a whole bunch of imports were not available, even common imports like `pandas`, `numpy` and `matplotlib` which were in the in the `requirements.txt` file....  why is this ?

Answer (score 0):

actually when installing modules it uses predownloaded versions, this means it will not download them again until you ask by using --no-cache-dir :)