# copying modules from python 3.10 to 3.11 (does not work)

Tags: python, pip, upgrade

I am trying to copy modules from python `3.10` to `3.11`.
I am using `windows 11`.

- My understanding is that one just downloads and install the new version of python.
- I make sure that `python is added to path`.

i follow this instruction: [copying modules from python 3.10 to 3.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74190755/copying-modules-from-python-3-10-to-3-11)

i then do this:

```
python3.10 -m pip freeze > requirements.txt
python3.11 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

but it throws an error message:

```
'python3.10' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

So i do this:

```
where python
```

to get this:

```
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
```

I note the guidance here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_freeze/
which states this:

```
env1\bin\python -m pip freeze > requirements.txt
env2\bin\python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

So my question is, with my paths and the above instruction, how do I implement the correct command so that all the packages are successfully updated in the new python version?

**update**:

is this the correct implementation ?

```
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python -m pip freeze > requirements.txt
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python -m install -r requirements.txt
```

And if so do i need to copy the requirements.txt file to the new path ?

Comment: _is this the correct implementation ?_, yes seems fine.

Comment: I'm failing to understand why you don't just install the 3.11 modules properly instead of hoping the 3.10 ones might work?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, because I have many running apps that rely on these and I want to make sure everything is there even if there is too much. (i can do upgrades later if needed).

Comment: [\[SO\]: How to install a package for a specific Python version on Windows 10? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57883242/4788546).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify full path of python,

```
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe -m pip freeze > requirements.txt
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

or It would be better for you to create a link for python in the same directory,

```
cd C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\
mklink Python310\python3.10.exe Python310\python.exe
mklink Python311\python3.11.exe Python311\python.exe
```

Later on when you want to use `python3.xx`, just type `python3.xx` it will work. Now you can use the same command you are using.

Comment: with the first method, would i need to copy the `requirements.txt` file to the new path ?

Comment: You can run it from anywhere, since `requirements.txt` will be created in the folder you run from, same will be used while installing package for python3.11.

Comment: so the `requirements.txt` file would exist in whatever folder the command was run from.  So a standard `windows11` command prompt opens here `C:\Users\admin` and this is where the `requirements.txt` would exist ?

Comment: When you run first command containing `> requirements.txt` this will create the file in the directory its run from.
And for running 2nd command, you need the `requirements.txt`.

Comment: much appreciated.  i have marked this as the correct answer and upvoted.... no doubt i will be revisiting at `3.12`.