# Import function in python not working properly after uninstalling pyenv

Tags: python, pip, python-import, python-module, python-3.11

Previously I have been experimenting with pyenv and a few hours ago i wanted to fully uninstall and remove it from my computer. After doing so everything in python stopped working. Including VScode. So I uninstalled everything and re-installed both python and VScode. That did fix most of the problem but, after trying to get back into a project that i was working on. I have discovered that import has stopped working. I can only import from the same directory of the running python file, and nothing else would work.

I am sure that i have successfully installed the modules using

`pip install <package_name>`

after doing do so the import still has yellow underlining and it says "Could not be resolved from source"

[Screen shot of what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcOhJ.png)

after checking the module is installed, i think it is installed under the path

`c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages`

I'm not sure if this is the correct path or how to fix this. THis is my first time running into this issue, and I have been trying to fix this problem for the past 2-3 hours. In that time I have also tried multiple attempts of uninstalling and re-installing.

Nothing has worked so far. How would i fix this.

Comment: you are probably installing to the wrong python. To be sure, do this: `python -m pip install <package_name>`

Comment: also see this related issue:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75354886/copying-modules-from-python-3-10-to-3-11-does-not-work

Comment: I have tried that before but it still doesn't work. It shows up with requirements already satisfied with the path that I gave above. I made sure that I removed the packages completely and reinstalled everything. It still says this.

Comment: `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages` This is the path that apparently import is trying to look for the packages but instead, the pip install is installing packages in the path above.

Comment: make sure that you have added python to path in the windows system.