How to install packages installed in a python Virtual Environment into a new Virtual Environment?
It is as simple as the title says. I've tried:
pip install --no-index --find-links=".../another-venv/Lib/site-packages/" django

but I got the error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for django

Which tells me I'm not going right about this since django is actually in the given location. If there is a proper way to do this (that I really hope is possible 'cause my internet is terrible and installing the packages from scratch every time is absolutely atrocious) I will thank the help a lot.

Why not use a package manager (poetry, pipenv, uv, etc.), generate a lock file of all the current dependencies, then re-install them into the new venv? Why do you need to copy from 1 venv to another?

Possible duplicates: 1) how to copy modules from one virtualenv to another, 2) How to move installed packages to a newly created virtual environment ?

@GinoMempin I have no idea what I'm doing. The method is not important. The result I need is that the packages I have installed in one venv I can have them in another. Thats all. Can you elaborate on the method you are sugesting?

It's explained in the linked posts I've mentioned in my previous comment. But basically, you reinstall the packages in the new venv (you say it's "atrocious", but it's also the most correct and safest way of doing it, because it makes sure all the paths are correct, etc.). From your old venv, do a pip freeze > requirements.txt then on the new venv do a pip install -r requirements.txt. It's better if you were using a package manager so you generate .lock file instead and re-install with that.

If you really just want to duplicate the venv on the same machine, see the first part of this answer which is just basically copying the files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8794404/2745495

If you really want to avoid installing because of internet issues and you are just using virtualenv (no fancy package managers) try the answera here which recommend virtualenv clonging: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59733071/2745495

Probably your question could be rephrased as "How to pip-install from cache only (no internet connection)?". -- Indeed pip maintains a cache of all the distribution packages (sdists and wheels) it has already downloaded. So assuming your pip version is recent enough, there should be ways to get access to the previously downloaded distribution packages and install them in a new environment without needing to access internet. Maybe try pip cache django to get started and read this: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/caching/

As it turns out, it does not seem straightforward to install from cache directly. -- Maybe this tool can help: https://github.com/akx/pip-local-cache-index. It should help extract the distribution packages from pip's cache into a specific directory (a so-called "wheelhouse"), and then it is straightforward to pip-install from the wheelhouse without internet connection.
